# Did prophet Lut become a prophet after Allah's covenant with Ibrahim?

Tags: prophets, prophet-ibrahim, prophet-lut

Ibn Kathir mentions in stories of prophet that Lut is nephew of Ibrahim.

Question: Did he become prophet after Allah's covenant with ibrahim?

> And also from my offspring, but my covenant does not extend to the evildoers [Quran 2:124](https://quran.com/2/124)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with ibrahims covenant? The verse you are quoting is talking about Gods covenant; *"[Abraham] said, "And of my descendants?" [ Allah ] said, "My covenant does not include the wrongdoers."*

Comment: I was thinking to do so, but at the moment I think the question *"prophet Ibrahims covenant"* is based on a misinterpretation of the verse 2:124, as it is Allah's covenant that is mentioned and not Ibrahims. I could add this as an answer I'd you think it is enough.

Comment: See my answer and edit.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is **Yes**.

Allah says:

> فَآمَنَ لَهُ لُوطٌ ۘ وَقَالَ إِنِّي مُهَاجِرٌ إِلَىٰ رَبِّي ۖ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْعَزِيزُ الْحَكِيمُ
>
> **And Lot believed him**. [Abraham] said, "Indeed, I will emigrate to [the service of] my Lord. Indeed, He is the Exalted in Might, the Wise."

[Quran 29:26](https://quran.com/29/26)

Believed him to be a prophet of Allah and emigrated with him, he believed and followed Ibrahim before becoming a prophet as it is clear in this verse.

Comment: You are right, I did not read the question well, I shall update my answer soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: Fair enough , feel Allah made lut prophet after that covenant, **lut believed him**

Comment: @Preordainment there are no proof that Lut became a Prophet after Allah's covenant to Ibrahim. Rather indications that he became before the covenant.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, based on my mediocre research, apparently, there is no mentioning regarding the relationship between Ibrahim and Lut and likewise comparing the precise time of their prophecy. But as further info. which might clarify the issue:

In some books, the names of prophets are in order (respectively) as following (that, logically its order can prove/answer the issue):

> 1 .ا .حضرت آدم. 2 .حضرت ادريس. 3 .حضرت نوح. 4 .حضرت هود. 5 .حضرت صالح. 6
>   .حضرت ابراهيم. 7 . حضرت اسماعيل. 8 .حضرت لوط. 9 .حضرت اسحاق. 10.حضرت
>   يعقوب. 11 .حضرت يوسف. 12 .حضرت شعيب. 13 .حضرت موسى. 14 .حضرت داوود.
>   15.حضرت ایوب. 16 .حضرت یونس. 17 .حضرت زکریا. 18 .حضرت یحیی. 19 .حضرت عیسی. (7)
>
> 1. Adam … 6. Ibrahim … 8. Lut

In the message of the Holy Quran, they are as following:

> .ا. حضرت آدم. 2 .حضرت ادريس. 3 .حضرت نوح. 4 .حضرت هود. 5 .حضرت صالح. 6
>   .حضرت ابراهيم. 7 .حضرت اسحاق. 8 .حضرت اسماعيل. 9 .حضرت لوط. 10 .حضرت
>   يعقوب. 11 .حضرت يوسف. 12.حضرت ايوب. 13 .حضرت شعيب. 14 .حضرت موسى. 15
>   .حضرت هارون. 16 .حضرت اشموعيل. 17.حضرت الياس. 18 .حضرت اليسع. 19 .حضرت
>   ذوالكفل. 20 .حضرت داوود. 21 .حضرت سليمان. 22.حضرت يونس. 23 .حضرت
>   زكريا. 24 .حضرت يحيى. 25 .حضرت عيسى. 26 .حضرت عزير. 27 .حضرت محمد
>   پيامبر الشان اسلام).
>
> … 6. Ibrahim … 9. Lut

Hence, (AFAIK) it can be inferred that prophet Lut has been (appointed as a prophet, as a kind of Allah's covenant) after prophet Ibrahim …

**Conclusion:**

There is no such matter in the holy Quran (about the exact time of ...), besides, perhaps we can declare that there is no guarantee about the accuracy of that mentioned hadith(s) …, eventually, considering that there might be several tafsirs regarding Quranic verses, consequently, I found the following tafsir (which seemed to be correct) in the translation + Tafsir of this verse, that says:

…[Abraham] said, "And of my descendants?" [Allah] said, "My covenant does not include the wrongdoers." (and only those descendants of you who are pure and Ma’soom, deserve such position).

So, occasionally there are some other sentences which are leaving out/hidden, but can be inferred from the other visible parts of the sentences …
and so forth, although it can be inferred from the above-mentioned Quranic verse and hadith (regarding the name/orders of prophets) that Prophet Lut was after prophet Ibrahim.

(God willing, the answer can help you at least to some extent)

---

Source:

- [wiki.ahlolbait.com](http://wiki.ahlolbait.com/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D9%87_124_%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87_%D8%A8%D9%82%D8%B1%D9%87)
- [www.pasokhgoo.ir](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/22915)
- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/2:124)

Comment: Yes, perhaps those can be helpful as related issues, well done. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score 0):

Since you edited your question, to "Allah's covenant", my old answer is not relevant anymore and is removed.

Basically you are asking if Lut became a Prophet before or after this event:

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when Abraham was tried by his Lord with commands and he fulfilled them. [ Allah ] said, "Indeed, I will make you a leader for the people." [Abraham] said, "And of my descendants?" [ Allah ] said, "My covenant does not include the wrongdoers."
>
> [Surat Al-Baqarah, verse 124](https://quran.com/2/124)

We need to know when this happened in order to answer that. We can't know for sure, but at least we know that Abraham already had fulfilled the commands of his Lord, i.e this is after Abraham was about to sacrifice his son:

> And when he reached with him [the age of] exertion, he said, "O my son, indeed I have seen in a dream that I [must] sacrifice you, so see what you think." He said, "O my father, do as you are commanded. You will find me, if Allah wills, of the steadfast."
>
> [Surat As-Saffat, verse 102](https://quran.com/37/102)

The sacrifice was after the event when Lot believed in Abraham:

> **And Lot believed him.** [Abraham] said, "Indeed, I will emigrate to [the service of] my Lord. Indeed, He is the Exalted in Might, the Wise."
>
> [Surat Al-Ankabut, verse 26](https://quran.com/29/26)

So if Lot became a Prophet directly after believing in Abraham, we can conclude that he became a Prophet **before Allah's covenant with Ibrahim**.

However, if we don't know for sure when he became a Prophet we cannot know for sure if it was before or after! But then again, if we interpret that the son who was sacrificed by Ibrahim was Ishaq (and not Ismael, because there are [different opinions who was sacrificed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/36770/15201)), then we can also conclude that he was a Prophet before the covenant:

> But when he saw their hands not reaching for it, he distrusted them and felt from them apprehension. They said, "Fear not. **We have been sent to the people of Lot**."
>
> And his Wife was standing, and she smiled. Then We gave her **good tidings of Isaac** and after Isaac, Jacob.
>
> [Surat Hud, verse 70-71](https://quran.com/11/70-71)

I.e Lot was a Prophet when Ishaq still wasn't born, and because Ishaq was about to be sacrificed when he grows older.

### Conclusion

It's most likely that Lut became a Prophet before Allah's covenant with Ibrahim.

Comment: Question edited, lut is not offspring of Ibrahim but is an imam

Comment: @Preordainment This is the second time you edit your question... Now again the answer is not relevant anymore

Comment: @Preordainment i advice you to re edit the question and ask another question with your edited question (I. e current) content.

Comment: Will start another bounty :-),inshaAllah

Comment: @Preordainment the issue is that when you edit your question so much the answers will not be relevant to the question anymore. Therefore people come and read the answers and feel they are wrong and not answering the  question, then they downvote the answers. This is why all anwers here are down voted, including this. The bounty isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

Did Lot become a prophet after the covenant of God with Abraham?
Lot was one of the close relatives of Ibrahim (peace be upon him) who believed in him after his deliverance from the fire; He then emigrated to Palestine with Abraham. Although Lot (pbuh) himself was a prophet, he was a follower of Ibrahim's religion and Ibrahim (pbuh) was his Imamate.

Ref:https://wikifeqh.ir/%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%DB%8C%D9%85#foot230